# nodejs modify server to accept only requests from array of IPs

Tags: arrays, node.js, ip

I've a TCP server which I need to modify, to accept only requests from predefined IPs. My idea was to create an array, containing all IPs which are allowed, but how to do the check and how to put this check around my existing code?

code:

```
// Load the TCP Library
var net = require('net')

 // Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.setKeepAlive(true)

    // TODO: Add mysql connection list entry
    console.log('connected', socket.remoteAddress)

    socket.on('close', function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        // TODO: Add mysql connection list entry
        console.log('disconnected', socket.remoteAddress)
    })
}).listen(5000);

 // Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
 console.log("Server running at port 5000");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the wrong tool for the job. You should configure access to the application using the **system firewall**. Firewalls allow you to:

- select ip ranges in a flexible manner
  e.g blocking as well as allowing
- work with different ip versions
- work with different protocols
- better integrate into IT infrastructure

However, if you don't have access to the firewall and you need something quick and dirty you could easily kick connections that are not in your list by checking the ip address against a list:

```
var allow_list = ['10.1.1.1', '10.1.1.2'];

var net = require('net')
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    if (allow_list.indexOf(socket.remoteAddress) < 0) {       
       socket.destroy();
       return;
    }

    socket.setKeepAlive(true)

    // do stuff
}).listen(5000);

console.log("Server running at port 5000");
```

Comment: the check fails, seems like NodeJS is displaying a ugly version of the IP adress. Any idea how to fix this? For example, the output when a client connetcs: `connected ::ffff:127.0.0.1`As you may see, it doesn't only show the IP address, there is something (::ffff:) in front of the IP.

Comment: Then put that ip in your allow_list, i.e. ['::ffff:127.0.0.1', '::ffff:10.1.1.1']. These are ip6 formats. But like I say you are better off controlling access via your firewall.